# Saving data in LocalStorage in Ionic Application

Tags: arrays, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have an ionic app in which I have 7 input fields. what I am doing is I am saving those values from input fields into localstorage. below is my code in angularjs controller :

```
window.localStorage.setItem('Frames', JSON.stringify(PositionFrames));
$scope.Save = function () {

    var FrameValues = {
        "PositionName": $scope.data.PositionName,
        "box1": 'j0' + $scope.data.box1,
        "box2": 'j1' + $scope.data.box2,
        "box3": 'j2' + $scope.data.box3,
        "box4": 'j3' + $scope.data.box4,
        "box5": 'j4' + $scope.data.box5,
        "box6": 'gr' + $scope.data.box6
    };
    var temp = [];
    tmp = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('Frames'));
        temp.push(tmp);
        temp.push(FrameValues);

        window.localStorage.setItem('Frames', JSON.stringify(temp));
    // window.localStorage['Frames'] = JSON.stringify(temp)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));

};
```

Whenever I hit button to save data and print data in console.log I can see following results :

```
[[[{"PositionName":"Home","box1":90,"box2":90,"box3":90,"box4":90,"box5":90,"box6":90}],{"PositionName":"Amrit","box1":"j058","box2":"j161","box3":"j2143","box4":"j3152","box5":"j4157","box6":"gr159"}],{"PositionName":"Amrit","box1":"j058","box2":"j161","box3":"j2143","box4":"j3152","box5":"j4157","box6":"gr159"}]
```

However if you see data in not in order, I dont know why it is not in format like this [{},{},{}]. I cannot figure out where these additional [[[ are coming from.

How do I solve it ?

Thanks Fellas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks

following solved this problem

for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) { temp.push(tmp[i]) }

hope this will help someone